# Mutate rows based on maching to user defined strings that works universally

Tags: r, pattern-matching, dplyr, stringr, grepl

I have a data like this

```
 clas=c("CD_1","X.2_2","K$2_3","12k3_4",".A_5","xy_6")
 df <- data.frame(clas)
> df
    clas
1   CD_1
2  X.2_2
3  K$2_3
4 12k3_4
5   .A_5
6   xy_6
```

and I would like to change some rows that match this condition

if the strings after `_` are 4,5 and 6 replace the strings before the `_` with string `B`. So the output should like this;

```
    clas
1   CD_1
2  X.2_2
3  K$2_3
4 12kB_4
5   .B_5
6   xB_6
```

Thanks!

**EDIT::**

SO If I have data like this:

```
    clas
1   CD_1
2  X.2_2
3  K$2_3
4 12k3_4
5   .A_5
6  xy_11
```

Then applying your solution,

```
df %>% mutate(clas = str_replace(clas, "(.)(_[4511])", "B\\2"))

    clas
1   CB_1
2  X.2_2
3  K$2_3
4 12kB_4
5   .B_5
6  xB_11
```

But I only want to match `11` not `1`. How can we do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

clas <- c("CD_1","X.2_2","K$2_3","12k3_4",".A_5","xy_6")
df <- data.frame(clas)

df %>% mutate(clas = str_replace(clas, "(.)(_[456])", "B\\2"))
```

Here putting the matching pattern creates a match with 3 groups, the first containing the whole expression match `._[456]`, the second containing the `.` part and the third containing the `_[456]` part.

`\\2` accesses the third group (0 indexing) and so you replace the whole pattern `._[456]` with `B` followed by whatever matched `_[456]` where `[456]` is a character matching any of the options inside the brackets.

EDIT:

Each character inside of `[]` is treated individually, so `[1111]` is no different from `[1]` because that pattern only matches a single character that is either a 1 or 1 or 1 or 1. Instead you need to use `|` so you have `(.)(_[45]|_11)`. This matches `_4` or `_5` or `_11` in the second pattern group. Also if you want to match 1-9 but not 11 or 15 you need to use `(.)(_[45])$` where `$` is the end-of-string indicator. Go look at the cheatsheet and test these out on [RegExr](http://regexr.com).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. Let's say we have more than three numbers not just 4,5,6 how we implement that? For example seq(1,10) is not working inside of `"(.)(_[456])"` I assume ?

Comment: Well all the options for matching are inside of `[]`, so you can put in `[123456789]` or simply `[1-9]`. Have a look at this [regular expression cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf), the only tricky part here is the use of the `\\2` back-reference.

Comment: Your solution is great but I just realized one minor issue in the real data.frame. Could you check the OP's EDIT part ?

Comment: Editted my answer.

Comment: Thanks for guidance and help:). Really appreciated!!